# Find relation between displacement and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, power, displacement

> “A body is moving unidirectionally under the influence of a source of constant power. Find the relationship between displacement $s$ and time $t$.”

I proved it using dimensional homogeneity.
Power has dimensions $${[ML^2T^{-3}]}.$$

As it is constant and mass M is also constant,
So, $${[L^2T^{-3}]}$$is constant.

Hence ${L^2}\propto{T^3}$

So, L  $\propto{T^{3/2}}$

But this method feels like a trick proof or maybe not work in all situations (for example, here we had constant mass, but in other times we may not have that)

I feel that there is probably a better and concrete method through calculus. Can someone please help me out here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I find your solution much better and much more elegant that suggested in the answer.

Comment: yes there is one method through calculus [commenting so I can get back to it and be forced to answer :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

If the power is applied from time $t=0$, when the object is at rest, then at time $t$,
$$\frac12 m v^2 =Pt.$$
Writing $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$, separating variables and preparing to integrate,
$$\int_0^{s_1} ds =\int_0^{t_1} \sqrt{\frac{2Pt}{m}} dt$$
So
$$s_1=\frac23 \sqrt{\frac{2P}{m}} t_1^{\ 3/2}$$
We can now drop the '1' subscript. It has served its purpose.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I love your dimensions approach, though, as you know, it won't yield dimensionless numerical factors.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wanted to know the calculus way, because I needed to put in real values and get the answer (which would have only been possible by knowig the proportionality constant)

Answer (score 0):

Your method works. You can also do this by considering that power $$P=\vec F \cdot \vec v = Fv$$ since the problem says "unidirectional" meaning $\vec F$ and $\vec v$ are in the same direction. Note also, that $$F=m\frac{v}{t}$$ so that $$P=m\frac{v^2}{t}$$ or $$Pt=mv^2$$ and noting that power and mass are constant, we can write $$v^2=kt$$ for some constant $k$.
Remembering that $$v=\frac{x}{t}$$ we can also write $$\frac{x^2}{t^2} = kt$$ or $$x^2=kt^3$$ or $$x \propto t^\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: How did you write F=mv/t?

Comment: Acceleration a = v/t only when a is constant (w.r.t time) and initial velocity =0

Comment: Because $F=ma$ and $a=v/t$.

Comment: If the force is constant, then so is $a$. It also doesn't matter if the the initial velocity was not $0$. You get the exact same result. Try it.

Comment: Force is not constant. Power is constant

Comment: Yes but here velocity is not constant. (Otherwise a would be 0)

Comment: Why would it be zero?

Comment: Constant velocity => acceleration =0

Comment: Acceleration is the rate of change in velocity.

Comment: But if change in magnitude of velocity =0, also direction is constant, => velocity is constant, thus Acceleration =0 => force =0 => power =0 not possible

Comment: Hence velocity is changing

Comment: It is proportional to the power 3/2 not $\frac{t^3}{2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124586/discussion-between-infinitecool23-and-joseph-h).